# Weak form of Elliptic problem with mixed Dirichlet & Neumann conditions

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, weak-solution, l2-norm

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ in a bounded polygon domain and $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ known function.We split the boundary into two parts $\partial \Omega_{1}$ and $\partial \Omega_{2}$ such that $\partial \Omega =\partial \Omega_{1} \cup \partial \Omega_{2}.$
The elliptic problem of  Dirichlet & Neumann conditions is :

\begin{align*}
-\Delta u +u &=f \quad in \quad \Omega \subset\mathbb{R}^2 \\
u&=0 \quad in \quad \partial \Omega_{1}   \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{n}}&=1 \quad in \quad \partial \Omega_{2} 
\end{align*}

It was asked to write the problem in a weak form in a suitable solution space $\mathcal{V}$ and the bilinear form $a(\cdot,\cdot):\mathcal{V} \times \mathcal{V} \to \mathbb{R}$ as long as a norm $||\cdot||_{\mathcal{V}}$ and show that is indeed a norm.

**My beginning thought** :

\begin{align*}
-\Delta u+u &=f \\
-\Delta u v+uv &=fv \\
-\int_{\Omega}\Delta u v dV+ \int_{\Omega}uv dV&=\int_{\Omega}fv dV \\
\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dV- \int_{\partial \Omega_{2}}v \nabla u \cdot \vec{n} dS  + \int_{\Omega}uv dV&=\int_{\Omega}fv dV \\
\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dV- 1 + \int_{\Omega}uv dV&=\int_{\Omega}fv dV \\
\end{align*}

So $$a(u,v) = \int_{\Omega} u'(x) \cdot  v'(x) dx- 1 + \int_{\Omega}u (x)\cdot v(x) dx=\int_{\Omega}f(x) \cdot v(x) dx \quad \text{(1)}$$

in $\mathcal{V}_{h}$ subspace of $\mathcal{V}$

$$a(u,v) = \int_{\Omega} u_{h}'(x) \cdot  v_{h}'(x) dx- 1 + \int_{\Omega}u(x) \cdot v_{h(x)} dx=\int_{\Omega}f(x) \cdot v_{h}(x) dx  \quad \text{(2)} $$

Subtracting (1) from (2) we obtain :
$$\int_{\Omega} \left(u'(x)- u'_{h}(x)\right) v'_{h}dx = 0$$

but $$||u ||_{\mathcal{V}} = \left( \int_{\Omega}(v'(x))^2 dx\right)^{1/2}$$ is indeed a norm for the space $\mathcal{V}$

\begin{align*}
||u - u_{h} ||_{\mathcal{V}} &= \inf_{v_{h} \in \mathcal{V}_{h}} \\
||u - u_{h} ||_{\mathcal{V}}^2&=  \int_{\Omega} \left( u'(x) -v'_{h}(x)  \right)\left( u'(x) -v'_{h}(x)  \right) dx \\
&= \int_{\Omega} \left( u'(x) -v'_{h}(x)  \right) u'(x)   dx -
\underbrace{\int_{\Omega} \left( u'(x) -v'_{h}(x)  \right) u'_{h}(x)   dx}_{G.O = 0 }\\
&= \int_{\Omega} \left( u'(x) -v'_{h}(x)  \right) u'(x)   dx - \underbrace{
\int_{\Omega} \left( u'(x) -v'_{h}(x)  \right) v'_{h}(x)   dx}_{G.O = 0 }
\end{align*}

Therefore $$||u - u_{h} ||_{\mathcal{V}}^2 =\int_{\Omega} \left( u'(x) -v'_{h}(x)  \right)\left( u'(x) -v'_{h}(x)  \right) dx \leq ||u-u_{h}||_{\mathcal{V}}||v-v_{h}||_{\mathcal{V}}  $$

and by the definition of inf, we must also have:

$$\inf_{v_{h} \in \mathcal{V}_{h}}   ||u-u_{h}||_{\mathcal{V}} \leq ||v-v_{h}||_{\mathcal{V}} $$

**right calculation (post)**

\begin{align*}
\int_{\partial \Omega}v \nabla u \cdot \vec{n} dS &=\int_{\partial\Omega_{1}} v \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - \int_{\partial \Omega_{2}} v \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} dV\\
&=0 + \int_{\partial\Omega_{2}} v \cdot 1 dV \\
&= \int_{\partial\Omega_{2}} v  dV
\end{align*}

$$\int_{ \Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dV +\int_{\partial \Omega_{2}} v  dV+ \int_{ \Omega}uv dV=\int_{\Omega}fv dV$$

Comment: I doubt that your form $a$ represents an inner product (though I have not proven it). I think that you want to multiply by $v$ your differential equation and then integrate by parts.

Comment: @nicoguaro, it does not since $a(u,v)\neq a(v,u)$. Tsiantakis, you need to pick appropriate test and trial spaces. They can be the same or different, but for your task, it is easier to pick them the same. Then the weak problem can be obtained by constraining $u$ to be in the trial space, multiplying the PDE by test functions, and if necessary, applying "integration by parts". That gives you the bilinear and linear forms you need. You can handle the Dirichlet b.c.s immediately by choosing the spaces properly, and Neumann b.c.s will be important after integration by parts.

Comment: I think that you answered your question. So, I suggest that you revert your edition and create an answer with it.

Comment: so it is right? @nicoguaro

Comment: You still need to write the space down. Also where does $-1$ come from?

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas from the boundary conditions

Comment: So $\int_{\partial\Omega_2} \nabla u\cdot\vec{n} v \text{d}s = \int_{\partial\Omega_2} 1v \text{d}s= 1$?

Comment: help me what I have done wrong?

Comment: I don't know whether you have done anything wrong. Maybe the space $V_h$ and the Neumann portion of the boundary $\partial\Omega_2$ are such that $\int_{\partial\Omega_2} v \text{d}s = 1$. But that is not generally true.

Comment: @Tsiantakis, I am going to give you another hint. It must be that $a(0,0) = 0$ for $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ to be an inner product. It is because that you evaluated the integral I am pointing out wrong.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on why, in your Right Calculation, you equate $\int_{\partial\Omega_1} v\,\partial u/\partial n\,dS$ with zero. Since $\partial u/\partial n$ isn't necessarily zero on $\partial\Omega_1$, it appears you're assuming something about the nature of $v$, what sort of properties it has.

Comment: Using the fact that $v=0  \quad \text{in} \quad  \partial \Omega  \quad  \forall   v \in  \mathcal{V}$

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis: That makes sense. A previous commenter mentioned you ought to make clear the properties you're assuming for test functions. So if $\mathcal{V}$ is zero at the boundary, make that clear.

Comment: yes indeed I am very sorry about that.i forgot to mention